# iOS - Realtime image filters like Snapchat's

Tags: ios, image-manipulation, snapchat

I'm trying to create a simple camera app, which will have Snapchat-like image effects...

I know how to detect faces with Core Image. What I don't know, is how to create and apply effects onto the final image! I don't have the first idea about those!

I searched for tutorials, but I had no luck! Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: You can try to use  dlib or OpenCV for facial landmarks. This libraries can be compiled for ios.

Comment: look into tutorials about working with pixels (bitmapata). You can write a `for` loop, right? So just go through each pixel via loop adjusting its value. A basic tutorial will show then you experiment to understand processing